# Graph neighbourhood matrix in which each pair of rows has at least one common column full of ones

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to understand a particular method of moments estimation algorithm. If you are interested in that, see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381776/why-does-y-moshe-vardi-use-this-specific-matrix-when-estimating-source-destinat) for more detailed description.

Long story short, I am trying to understand what it means for the neighbourhood matrix of a directed graph to have the following property: no element-wise product of each pair of rows results in a zero row. To put it another way, each pair of rows in the neighbourhood matrix has at least one common column full of ones. So e.g. (not necessarily a neighbourhood matrix) $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&1\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$ has this property while $\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ does not.

So specifically:

1.) How can you represent this kind or property in a more graph theoretical/linear algebra way? I can only talk about it in a "programmatic" way, i.e. for all pairs of rows it holds that their dot product is not equal to zero.

2.) What can you tell about a graph whose neighbourhood matrix satisfies this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *neighborhood matrix* is another name for *adjacency matrix*, the property means that every pair of nodes has a common out-neighbor.  That is, for all $i,j\in N$ with $i<j$, there exists at least one $k\in N$ such that $(i,k) \in A$ and $(j,k) \in A$.

Comment: Okay! Do you know how this idea could be expanded to a certain type of "adjacency matrix", where columns represent different origin-destination nodes and rows represent edges of the graph. Then an element $(i, j)$ is one iff the edge $i$ belongs to the path chosen to be used for the od-pair $j$ and otherwise zero. So for example, the graph $K_3$ would be a $6\times6$ identity matrix where columns represent the pairs $(1,2), (1,3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)$ and (in this case) the rows represent edges with same labels.

It could be that I should open a new question for this.

Comment: Yes, you should open a new question.